# Rename or copy a whole Redis database to another one?

Tags: redis

I have an application that get all its data from a Redis database (DB1), which is updated every hour by an external process. During this update, all the data in Redis is replaced.

To avoid having any errors on the main application when updating, I thought about having the updater process write to a secondary Redis database (DB2) and after finishing, switch this database with the one that the application is using.

I didn't find a way to rename or copy a whole Redis database, so the only way I can think of is to erase all keys from DB1 and than use [MOVE](http://redis.io/commands/move) to save all new keys from DB2 in DB1.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply have DB2 SLAVEOF DB1, poll it with INFO and checking for 
master_sync_in_progress: 0?

When you're about to perform your updates to DB1 then SLAVEOF NO ONE on DB2 (break the replication).  Perform your updates on DB1 while clients access the static (old) data on DB2; then reslave when the updates are complete on DB1.

Comment: Additionally you can do things in your application to check master_sync_in_progress and perform a sleep whenever that's non-zero; or you can arrange a synchronization using some sort of "Read/verify" strategy.  For example if you keep a "__GENERATION__" key which you atomically increment on DB1 after each batch of writes then your clients could do something like: WATCH __GENERATION__ MULTI GET xxx EXEC.  The GET command will success if (and only if) the __GENERATION__ was unmodified in the interim.

Comment: I didn't want to change the main application, but I guess there's no alternative.  I'm new to Redis, so I don't really get your last comment, but I'll do some reading. Thanks!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it really helped me, but just in case someone else wonders, I ended up duplicating the database (in the same Redis instance) and making the application read the db number from an environment variable. This way I can just change the env var before/after the update process.